# Textillate word cycle display in line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a textilate.js code that cycles words. I have came to some code, but I am not there yet, because my p tags and the words that keep cycling must be on the same line. Preferably, the space of between 'text' and 'blabla' should have a fixed width.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kavTe/190/)

```
$('.texts').textillate({
minDisplayTime: 1000, 
in: { effect: 'flipInY', sync: true }, 
out :{  delay: 3, effect: 'lightSpeedOut', sync: true},
loop: true });




<p> text</p> <ul class="texts">
        <li>Some Title</li>   
        <li>Another Title</li>
        <li>Yet another</li>
    </ul> 
  <p>
   bla bla
  </p>
```

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kavTe/193/) what you want?

Comment: or probably [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kavTe/194/) without the `float`s..

Comment: Thank you kind sir, that works out just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kavTe/197/)

Please update your CSS as follows

```
.texts {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
p{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

The problem with your code was that the `<p>` tags were taking full width and thus they were going down.

Comment: Oh glad that it helped you... :)